# VSCode launch.json file to debug CoffeeScript Meteor app: generated files not found

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to setup VSCode 1.6.1 to be able to debug Meteor 1.4.1.2 apps written in CoffeeScript 1.11.1_1.

In the VSCode launch.json file, I have defined two attach configurations:
- one to debug the server-side code using the built-in node debugger
- one to debug the client-side code using the chrome debugger extension

After a debugger statement, I have put breakpoints in all 3 parts of the code of the Meteor leaderboard example: in the isomorphic section running on both the client and the server, as well as in the client-only and server-only sections of the code.

When I attach either debugger while the app is paused on the debugger statement, the breakpoints turn grey with the warning: *"breakpoints ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?)"*

The launch.json is file is the following:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/leaderboard.coffee",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "preLaunchTask": null,
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy"
            ],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js",
                "${workspaceRoot}/.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/app/app.js"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach Server",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5858,
            "address": "localhost",
            "restart": false,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js"],
            "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "remoteRoot": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach Client",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222,
            "address": "localhost",
            "sourceMaps": true
            // "url": "//localhost:9222/"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command.PickProcess}",
            "port": 5858,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outFiles": []
        }
    ]
}
```

The source leaderboard.coffee file is the following:

```
class Player
  constructor: (@name, @score = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)) ->
  inc: -> @score = @score + 1

class Leaderboard extends Mongo.Collection
  insertNewPlayer: (playerName) ->
    player = new Player(playerName)
    @insert player

  insertPlayers: (playerNames) ->
    # @remove({})
    @insertNewPlayer(playerName) for playerName in playerNames
    self = @

  insertRank: =>
    sortedPlayers = @find {}, {sort: {score: -1, name: 1}}, {reactive: false}
                      .fetch()
    previousPlayer = sortedPlayers[0]
    rank = 1
    @update {_id: previousPlayer._id}, {$set: {rank: rank, rankStr: "#{rank}"}}
    tiedCounter = 1
    for player in sortedPlayers[1..]
      do (player) =>
        if player.score is previousPlayer.score
          tiedCounter = tiedCounter + 1
          @update {_id: player._id}, {$set: {rank: rank, rankStr: "-"}}
        else
          rank =  rank + tiedCounter
          @update {_id: player._id}, {$set: {rank: rank, rankStr: "#{rank}"}}
        previousPlayer = player
    self = @

debugger
aflLeaderboard = new Leaderboard("aflLeaderboard") unless aflLeaderboard?

# debugger
if Meteor.isClient
  Template.leaderboard.helpers
    players: -> aflLeaderboard.find {}, {sort: {score: -1, name: 1}}

  #Template.leaderboard.events
  #  'click tr#sortButtonRow>th#sortButtonCell>button': leaderboard = players()

  Template.player.events
    'click tr>td>button': ->
      aflLeaderboard.update {_id: player._id}, {$inc: {score: 1}}

# debugger
if Meteor.isServer
  Meteor.startup ->
    if not (aflLeaderboard? and aflLeaderboard.findOne({})?)

      aflLeaderboard.insertPlayers [
        "Heath Shaw"
        "Alex Rance"
        "Easton Wood"
      ]
      aflLeaderboard.insertRank()
      self = @
```

Is it really a source map problem?
If it is, what's wrong with my launch.json file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think you need check this two property:

```json
"program": "${file}", //important, make sure debug current file
"outFiles": [//important, where to find sourcemap js file
"${workspaceFolder}/dist/api/api.js" 
]
```